# probability that customer buy item A . Given that customer buy only one item

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A convenience store customer buys product $A$ with probability $0.50$ and product $B$ with probability $0.75$.Given that she buys  $A$ the probability that she buys $B$ is $0.8$. Then what is the probability that she buys $B$ Given that  a customer buy only one item, is

What i try :: Here $P(A)=0.5$ and $P(B)=0.75$ and

$\displaystyle P\bigg(\frac{B}{A}\bigg)=.8\Longrightarrow \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=0.8\Longrightarrow P(A\cap B)=0.04$

As i understand we have to find

$\underbrace{P\bigg(\frac{B}{A}\bigg)}_{\text{probability of item B given that item A}}+\underbrace{P\bigg(\frac{B}{B}\bigg)}_{\text{probability of item B given that item B}}=0.8+1=1.8$

Is my process is correct, If not please help me How do i solve it, Thanks

Comment: Reality check: if your computed probability lies outside the interval $[0,1]$, you know to rethink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If she only buys one item, there are two possibilities:  $A$ or $B$.

$$P(B|A \cup B) = \frac{P(B)}{P(A) + P(B)}$$

The case of purchasing two objects is irrelevant.

And you should have seen that your reasoning was wrong once you computed a probability of $1.8$.

Comment: Thanks David. Is it not  $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Given the statement of the problem you can never buy *two* items, so $P(A \cap B) = 0$.